# Función JS dentro de bucle PHP hace referencia al último ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Estoy utilizando la librería [Croppie.js](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) para seleccionar una imagen y recortarla (después con AJAX la envío al servidor pero esto no es propio de dicha librería).

Todo esto funciona:

```js
// Start upload preview image
$(".gambar").attr("src", "https://via.placeholder.com/35x35");
var $uploadCrop, tempFilename, rawImg, imageId;

function readFile(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $(".upload-demo").addClass("ready");
      $("#cropImagePop").modal("show");
      rawImg = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  } else {
    swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
  }
}

$uploadCrop = $("#upload-demo").croppie({
  viewport: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
  enforceBoundary: true,
  enableExif: true,
});
$("#cropImagePop").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
  // alert('Shown pop');
  $uploadCrop
    .croppie("bind", {
      url: rawImg,
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("jQuery bind complete");
    });
});

$(".item-img").on("change", function() {
  imageId = $(this).data("id");
  tempFilename = $(this).val();
  $("#cancelCropBtn").data("id", imageId);
  readFile(this);
});
$("#cropImageBtn").on("click", function(ev) {
  $uploadCrop
    .croppie("result", {
      type: "base64",
      format: "jpeg",
      size: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      },
    })
    .then(function(resp) {
      $("#item-img-output").attr("src", resp);
      $("#cropImagePop").modal("hide");
      console.log("Imagen cortada");

      //Manda la imagen por AJAX a un documento PHP que la carga al servidor, esto funciona también

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          image: resp
        },
        url: "ajax/subirimagen.php",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("Imagen enviada al AJAX");
        }
      });
    });
});
// End upload preview image
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

label.cabinet {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.cabinet input.file {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
  margin-top: -30px;
}


/* Espacio donde se visualizará la imagen a recortar */

#upload-demo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.upload-demo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

img.gambar {
  max-width: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.p-0 {
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.css'>
<script src='https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.js'></script>

<!-- TABLA -->

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>estado</th>
        <th>fechacreado</th>
        <th>fotoperfil</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>ACTIVO</td>
        <td>2019</td>

        <td class="p-0">
          <label class="cabinet center-block">
          <figure>
          <img src="" class="gambar img-responsive" id="item-img-output">
          </figure>
          <input type="file" class="item-img file center-block" name="file_photo" /> </label>

        </td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




<!-- MODAL -->

<div class="modal fade" id="cropImagePop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
          EDITAR FOTO ID
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="upload-demo" class="center-block upload-demo"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Cerrar
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="cropImageBtn" class="btn btn-primary">
          CORTAR
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El problema viene cuando la tabla tiene más de un dato que recojo con un ciclo PHP, que se vería algo así:

[image: Tabla]

Usando el siguiente código:

```php
    <?php
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $estado = $row['estado'];
        $fechacreado = $row['fechacreado'];
        $fotoperfil = $row['fotoperfil'];
    
    ?>
        <tr class="text-center">
    
            <td>
                <?php echo $id; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $estado; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $fechacreado; ?>
            </td>
    
            <td class="p-0 text-center">
    
                <label class="cabinet center-block">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="" class="gambar img-responsive" id="item-img-output<?php echo $id ?>">
                    </figure>
    
                    <input type="file" class="item-img file center-block" name="file_photo" />
                </label>
    
            </td>
    
            <?php include("../html/modal_foto.php"); ?>
    
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Como podrán ver, lo que hago es "quemar" con PHP el `$id` a cada uno de los `id=*` tanto del `input file`, como del modal en ruta `html/modal-foto.php`. Ahora bien, lo mismo estoy haciendo para el script JS, así:

```js
// Start upload preview image
$(".gambar").attr("src", "https://tarjetero.com.co/old/demo/foto-perfil.png");
var $uploadCrop, tempFilename, rawImg, imageId;

function readFile(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $(".upload-demo").addClass("ready");
      $("#cropImagePop<?php echo $id ?>").modal("show");
      rawImg = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  } else {
    swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
  }
}

$uploadCrop = $("#upload-demo<?php echo $id ?>").croppie({
  viewport: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
  enforceBoundary: true,
  enableExif: true,
});
$("#cropImagePop<?php echo $id ?>").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
  // alert('Shown pop');
  $uploadCrop
    .croppie("bind", {
      url: rawImg,
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("jQuery bind complete");
    });
});

$(".item-img").on("change", function() {
  imageId = $(this).data("id");
  tempFilename = $(this).val();
  $("#cancelCropBtn<?php echo $id ?>").data("id", imageId);
  readFile(this);
});
$("#cropImageBtn<?php echo $id ?>").on("click", function(ev) {
  $uploadCrop
    .croppie("result", {
      type: "base64",
      format: "jpeg",
      size: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      },
    })
    .then(function(resp) {
      $("#item-img-output<?php echo $id ?>").attr("src", resp);
      $("#cropImagePop<?php echo $id ?>").modal("hide");
      console.log("Primer paso");
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          image: resp,
          // La siguiente variable es importante:
          codigo: <?php echo $id?>
        },
        url: "ajax/subirimagen.php",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("Entró al AJAX");
        }
      });
    });
});
// End upload preview image
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="cropImagePop<?php echo $id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel<?php echo $id ?>">
          EDITAR FOTO
          <?php echo $id ?>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="upload-demo<?php echo $id ?>" class="center-block upload-demo"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="cropImageBtn<?php echo $id ?>" onclick="readFile()" class="crop_image btn btn-primary">
          Crop
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El código anterior funciona, pero únicamente se ejecuta en la última vuelta del ciclo.

> **Entiendo que esto es debido a que estoy sobrescribiendo mis variables y siempre tomará las del final, la solución sería sacar el
> script JS del ciclo.**

---

### ¿Qué sucede?

Que entonces no podré usar los identificadores de mi ciclo y que estos afecten al script.

Dentro del envío que hago por AJAX a mi archivo `ajax/subirimagen.php` tengo:

```
<?php

$cropped_image = $_POST['image'];
$codigo = $_POST['id'];

list($type, $cropped_image) = explode(';', $cropped_image);
list(, $cropped_image) = explode(',', $cropped_image);
$cropped_image = base64_decode($cropped_image);

$image_name = $codigo . '.png';


file_put_contents('../img/'.$image_name, $cropped_image);
// add insert/update query to save filename in the database table
?>
```

Como les decía, al sacar el script del bucle, no voy a tener acceso a la variable `$id` y por consiguiente, valor `undefined` en la variable `$codigo` que es la que se encarga de guardar la imagen con el nombre exacto. Esto es muy importante, que la imagen guardada pueda localizar con el `$id` de la fila correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver la librería de cliente con el proceso en servidor? No entiendo lo que pretendes lograr. Desde el servidor envías los datos en tu vista HTML, la librería que usas luego, se debe encargar de procesar esos datos. La lógica del bucle en PHP se corre en el servidor, no puedes pretender que a la vez se ejecute el código de la librería cliente. Saludos

Comment: Como bien apunta @MauricioContreras, el principal problema aquí es **no entender cómo funciona Ajax**. El archivo .php al que va dirigida la petición Ajax no debe tener código .js, su función es recibir los datos que le mandas, procesarlos, crear lo que le estás pidiendo y devolverlo. Luego en el cliente recibes la respuesta y la muestras donde tengas que mostrarla. Si ese modo de funcionar no se entiende pronto estarás perdido en tu propio código.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio y Alfertson por sus comentarios, el AJAX no contiene JS, le estoy pasando la info con el data a un archivo PHP que es el que al final del lado del servidor procesa y guarda la imagen. La librería en JS unicamente recorta y decodificada la imagen en base64. Entiendo que esto parece más Spaghetti code, pero es la forma en que debería obtener el resultado, a menos que JS me permita crear un ID para nombrar la imagen dependiendo del bucle. Estoy abierto a sus atentos comentarios

Comment: Vuelvo a hacer hincapié en que estás mezclando lógica del servidor con lógica del cliente, específicamente aquí: `$uploadCrop = $("#upload-demo<?php echo $id ?>")`. Ese código es Javascript, corre en el navegador (cliente), donde no existe `PHP`. Por lo tanto esto: `<?php echo $id ?>` será el valor que envió el servidor como vista (*documento html*) y obviamente tendrá el último valor capturado en el bucle `while` que se ejecutó antes de enviar dicha vista. Tal vez lo que necesites es un [atributo `data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Saludos